# [Cocoa]How to pass messages between multi windows using NSNotification?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa and macOS application development.
I have two windows: MainMenu.xib and aWindow.xib, and each of them has its windowController.
I want to send a message to aWindow to let it perform a method, so in the windowController of aWindow, I write:

```
[aButton setTarget:self];
[aButton setAction:@selector(aMethod)];
```

And aWindow has a method called aMethod.

But it does not work.

After a longtime experiment, I figure out that, if MainMenu also has a method called aMethod, then the aButton on aWindow will execute the MainMenu's aMethod.

And I also tried NSNotification, with setting Observer:self, which leads to the same result as above.

I think this has something with the Response Chain, but I can't fully understand it.

So how can I make the aButton on aWindow have the action to let aWindow perform its aMethod?

Comment: In theory, what you want to do should be possible ... but there are scores of tiny details that can trip you up. My advice is to really sit down and learn how the responder chain works; without that knowledge, writing macOS apps is going to be a lot of frustration.

Comment: But let me also say that normally you would never send a message from a button in one window to the controller of a different window; the responder chain simply doesn't work that way. The idea is that commands are handled within the branch of the view hierarchy that receives the event (in this case a mouse click). The responder chain starts with the button control, goes to its enclosing views, up to the window, its controller, the document, and then the application. Other controllers, windows, window controllers, and documents are—by definition—excluded from that path.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thank you for your instruction. You say that"you would never send a message from a button in one window to the controller of a different window", but what I want is to send a message from aButton on aWindow to aWindow, so how can I do that?

Comment: Since aWindow is in the responder chain of every view it contains, it should be as simple as setting the action of the button to the desired selector. You don't need a target (aButton.target=nil). If that's not working, then something is amiss. Also be careful to use the correct selector (`-aMethod` and `-aMethod:` are two entirely different methods/selectors.)

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thanks! So what about NSNotificationcenter? I want an event on aWindow to post a notification to aWindow to perform aMethod, and the syntax of NSNotificationcenter requires an observer. If I set its observer as self, the event on aWindow will post a notification to MainMenu to perform its aMethod.

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` is a general purpose notification service, often referred to as "publish and subscribe." Any number of objects can register as observers (specifying a method that will receive the notifications). Any other object can then post a notification. The Notification Center forwards that notification to every object registered to receive it. It's generally used as a way of responding to events. For example, a scroll view will post a notification whenever its content has scrolled; an observer could observe that notification and enable/disable a "scroll to top" button.